# Can I make an HTML form perform two actions?

Tags: html, forms, http-post

Can I use my HTML form to perform multiple actions?

1. Post the information to another destination.
2. Navigate a user to another page once they submit the form.

At the moment I can post the filled form to the destination but cant navigate the user to another page using HTML specifically. Is there any method in HTML to do this?

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could use AJAX to submit the form, then JS to navigate to a different page.  You could also submit the form outright, then on the server side redirect the user.

Comment: thank you for your reply. actually i am working on goolge sites that have very limited compatibility. i cant use javescript js or any other programming language with the form..the form is on the google site..once the user is submitting the form it is moving to the blank page.. i want to rediect it to the page that i can design..google site is not working properly if i put any script in it.. any suggestions if i can do the actions with the submit button or if form can do multipe actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things are easy if you control the server and/or are on the same domain, then you can do a server side redirect. But since you are using salesforce surely you don't control that. Nevertheless, double check their documentation for a redirect option you can put in the form.

If that fails, one thing I'd try is to submit it to an iframe: add `<iframe name="foo" id="foo"></iframe>` somewhere to your html (you can hide it too if you want) and add `target="foo"` to your form. Then, also add an onsubmit javascript handler to the form that redirects after a delay to allow the form to be processed. The timing of the delay is likely to be a source of bugs btw, checking for errors in the submitted form can't be easily done across domains, you'd be guessing. Maybe an onload handler on the iframe can do the redirect though, I'm not sure, but worth a try.

This isn't guaranteed to work either, some sites don't like being in iframes. If that fails, you might try setting `target="_BLANK"` to submit the form to a popup window then redirect your main window using javascript or something. This will require you to give an instruction to the user to close the window.

Lastly, if you can submit the data via a server side API call to salesforce, that would be good too because then the plain redirect option is back under your control.

Comment: thank you adam for your reply. actually i am working on goolge sites that have very limited compatibility. i cant use javescript js or any other programming language with the form..the form is on the google site..once the user is submitting the form it is moving to the blank page.. i want to rediect it to the page that i can design..google site is not working properly if i put any script in it.. any suggestions if i can do the actions with the submit button or if form can do multipe actionsl

Answer (score 0):

You can use redirect after you perform whatever you are going to do on the first page (the one from form action)

Comment: Thank you boris for your reply. actually i am working on goolge sites that have very limited compatibility. i cant use javescript js or any other programming language with the form..the form is on the google site..once the user is submitting the form it is moving to the blank page.. i want to rediect it to the page that i can design..google site is not working properly if i put any script in it.. any suggestions if i can do the actions with the submit button or if form can do multipe actions

Comment: Can you change the HTML? Can you change the FORM action page?

Comment: yes i can change the html but as soon as i put any script in it..t will stop working..everything has t be done in html itself..google says that they accept javascript with html but its not working.. i have searche the new and got to know that we can only perform one action with one form??? any sugesstions